# How to change str to int in a list made of scientific notation

Tags: python, string, list, int, scientific-notation

I have a list, which looks like this:

```
['3.2323943e+00,   4.4316312e+00,   4.3174178e+00,   3.8661688e+00,   
3.6366895e+00,   3.4324592e+00,   3.3091351e+00,   3.1746527e+00,   
1.0588169e+00,   4.4036068e+00,   4.4692073e+00,   4.3857228e+00,   
4.2660739e+00,   4.1388672e+00,   4.0061081e+00,   3.8303311e+00']
```

How can I change it to be int (now shows me error, says it is str) in order to find mean and standard deviation?

Comment: It's not the scientific notation that's the problem, it's the fact that your values are in a list made up of one long string. "Scientific Notation" can easily be read as a float, from which you can get mean and standard deviation. See answers below for solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is like this:

```
old_list = ['3.2323943e+00,   4.4316312e+00,   4.3174178e+00,   3.8661688e+00,   3.6366895e+00,   3.4324592e+00,   3.3091351e+00,   3.1746527e+00,   1.0588169e+00,   4.4036068e+00,   4.4692073e+00,   4.3857228e+00,   4.2660739e+00,   4.1388672e+00,   4.0061081e+00,   3.8303311e+00']

new_list = [float(i) for i in old_list[0].split(',')]

>>> new_list
[3.2323943, 4.4316312, 4.3174178, 3.8661688, 3.6366895, 3.4324592, 3.3091351, 3.1746527, 1.0588169, 4.4036068, 4.4692073, 4.3857228, 4.2660739, 4.1388672, 4.0061081, 3.8303311]
```

You can then get your mean and std of your new list using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

mean_of_list = np.mean(new_list)

std_of_list = np.std(new_list)
```

To explain, your values are currently in a list comprising of one long string (which I've called `old_list`). My list comprehension splits that at the comma (using `.split(',')`), and turns it into a float, rather than a string (using `float(...)`)

**Note on ints vs. floats**

As pointed out by Patrick Artner in their post, it makes sense to cast to float, rather than int, because your values seem like floats (they have a seemingly relevant decimal part). If you actually wanted them as ints, simply do this:

```
new_list = [int(float(i)) for i in old_list[0].split(',')]
```

But your resulting list would be:

```
>>> new_list
[3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3]
```

Which is probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You cant, they are not ints, they are floating values.  And your list is a 1-element list of one big string holding comma seperated floating point values in mathematical notation:

```
floats = list(map(float,'3.2323943e+00,   4.4316312e+00,   4.3174178e+00,   3.8661688e+00,   3.6366895e+00,   3.4324592e+00,   3.3091351e+00,   3.1746527e+00,   1.0588169e+00,   4.4036068e+00,   4.4692073e+00,   4.3857228e+00,   4.2660739e+00,   4.1388672e+00,   4.0061081e+00,   3.8303311e+00'.split(",")))

print (floats)

mean = sum(floats)/len(floats)
variance = sum((x-mean)**2 for x in floats) / len(floats)
popul = variance**0.5

from pprint import pprint

print(floats)
print("Mean",mean)
print("Variance",variance)
print("Population",popul)
```

Output:

```
[3.2323943, 4.4316312, 4.3174178, 3.8661688, 3.6366895, 3.4324592, 3.3091351, 
 3.1746527, 1.0588169, 4.4036068, 4.4692073, 4.3857228, 4.2660739, 4.1388672, 
 4.0061081, 3.8303311]
Mean 3.74745516875
Variance 0.6742259030611121
Population 0.8211126007199695
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
list = [float(x) for x in '3.2323943e+00,   4.4316312e+00'.split(',')]
```

Returns:

```
[3.2323943, 4.4316312]
```

Simply add the rest of your data.

Comment: they are floats ... not ints .. and the list is no list but a string .... please test your answer before posting.